# Alternatives to geolocation for detecting users location

Tags: asp.net, seo, web

My website needs to detect the users country so I can then hone the content to this country.

Previously I tried geolocation but I think this had a negative affect on SEO and also led to a delay when the user first loaded the site.

I'm looking to detect country in another way e.g. perhaps via information available in the users browser if possible.

Has anyone detected the user location successfully without using geolocation?

Comment: Have you tried ESP? Works well for Google. :p

Answer (score 0):

One alternative would be to use the user's IP address, but this can be unreliable:

http://www.dotnetcurry.com/ShowArticle.aspx?ID=325

Comment: That was actually the ESP to which I was referring. It's OK as a rough guess of what country someone is in.